# why a set of all $2 \times 2$ matrices can be a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am sorry this is a stupid question, but I am really confused about why $2 \times 2$ matrix is not a vector, but all $2 \times 2$ matrices can be a vector space? According to the definition, the each element in a vector spaces is a vector. So, $2 \times 2$ matrix cannot be element in a vector space since it is not even a vector.

Comment: $2x2$ matrix *is* a vector (of dimension $4$).

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a vector.

Comment: A vector space is not made necessarily of real vectors, but of objects which behave ‘like’ vectors.

Answer (score 3):

That's an example of abstract vector spaces. They call vector spaces, but since the "object" that you are looking into have the properties of subspaces:

- Closed under multiplication;
- Closed under addition;
- Contains the $ \left\{ 0 \right\} $ "vector", or in this case, the null matrix.

You can affirm that it'll be a vector space.

To "visualize" that, try to imagine any matrix 2x2 added to another 2x2 matrix. You'll still be in a 2x2 matrix world. Same happens when multipling them... And because the null matrix is in the 2x2 matrix world, you can assume that it'll be a subspace, hence, a vector space.

[Watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgKwz5Ikpc8&index=15)
to get a better understanding of that kind of abstraction. It's hard to visualize...

Comment: Ok, then does "each element is a vector space is a vector" still hold in the definition of vector space?

Comment: You should specify "closed under multiplication" as "closed under scalar multiplication" since matrices can also be multiplicated

Comment: @Tianyi "each element IN a vector space is a vector" ? That's what you mean right? If so, the answer is yes. But it's better to stop seeing things like arrows in space... Try to open your mind and call something a vector if it behaves like a vector. 2x2 matrix world behaves like a vector, so each 2x2 matrix element is a "vector", not an arrow in space...

Comment: @Tianyi We really define "vector" to mean "an element of a vector space". A lot of teachers think it does their students a favor to say that a vector is something that has direction and length, which is maybe a useful simplification at first, but is no longer useful at the level you're studying at.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to think of e.g. $2\times 2$ matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as vectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c\\ d
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
All you need of vectors is to be able to add them and to multiply them by a scalar (subject to some commutation and distribution properties of these operations). All that is true for matrices too, thus, matrices are vectors. The major difference is that matrices constitute much richer world than vectors - it is even possible to multiply them to each other, which is not possible for vectors.

Comment: Thanks, but is this technically correct to say matrices are vectors?

Comment: @Tianyi It is perfectly correct. Think though that vectors and vectors are not the same. For example, vectors in ${\Bbb R}^2$ and vectors in ${\Bbb R}^3$ are of different nature.

Comment: Thank you! I just feel bad about my text book does not mention this idea at all...

Comment: But that's a more general idea of vectors! In the beggining the arrow with direction and length is good enough... haha

Comment: @Tianyi Numbers are vectors, elements of ${\Bbb R}^3$ are vectors, matrices are vectors, sequences are vectors, functions are vectors etc. The word "vector" just mean "en element of a vector space", but those spaces may be **very different** to each other.

Comment: @BrunoReis An arrow with direction and length is the best example that works in any occasion whatsoever.

Comment: @A.G If so, try to visualize polynomials vector spaces with that arrow definition... It isn't that trivial! When we open our mind to visualizing vectors as objects that behave like them, it makes more sense, at least for me, than trying to always see a geometric meaning for vector spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Put in an easy way, if we completely disregard matrix multiplication and instead focus on adding matrices and multiplying them by a scalar, we can treat a matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} &\ldots & a_{1m} \\ \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\ a_{n1} & \ldots & a_{nm} \end{pmatrix}$$
as a "big vector" $v$ with entries 
$$a=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} \\ \vdots \\a_{1m} \\ a_{21} \\ \vdots \\ a_{2m}\\ \vdots \\ a_{nm} \end{pmatrix}$$
Since addition and multiplication by a scalar are entry-wise, the two structures are basically the same: there is no difference in writing the matrix in a "square" form or as a vertical vector if we are only interested in linear combinations. Given two matrices $A$ and $B$ and two scalars $\lambda, \mu \in K$, we can either express a linear combination as

$$\lambda A+\mu B=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda a_{11} &\ldots & \lambda a_{1m} \\ \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\ \lambda a_{n1} & \ldots & \lambda a_{nm} \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix}\mu b_{11} &\ldots & \mu b_{1m} \\ \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\ \mu b_{n1} & \ldots & \mu b_{nm} \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}\lambda a_{11}+\mu b_{11} &\ldots & \lambda a_{1m}+ \mu b_{1m} \\ \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\ \lambda a_{n1}+\mu b_{n1} & \ldots & \lambda a_{nm}+\mu b_{nm} \end{pmatrix}$$
Clearly, if we express the two matrices in "vector" form, we obtain a vector whose entries are the same as the ones in the matrix $\lambda A+\mu B$.

If we indicate $n \times m$ matrices over the field $K$ as $M_{n\times m}(K)$, we are stating that there exists an isomorphism
$$\Phi:M_{m\times n}(K) \to K^{n\times m}$$
that maps the matrix $(a_{ij})_{1\le i \le n, 1\le j \le m}$ to the vector of $K^{n \times m}$ with entries $a_{ij}$. This means that there exists an invertible map that respects the vector space operations (i.e. linear combinations), which, in laymen terms, means that we can treat matrices as vectors as far as we are only concerned with addition and multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: Thanks!!! It is really helpful!!!!