# Why can matrices be represented as column vectors in an abstract vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Recently, I solved this question:

"Let $V = \mathbb{R}^{2\cdot 2}$  with basis
$\mathbf{B}$ = $(\mathbf{b_1}, \mathbf{b_2}, \mathbf{b_3}, \mathbf{b_4}, )$, where

$\mathbf{b1} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbf{b2} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbf{b3} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbf{b4} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Thus, n = dim(V) = 4. The map f: $V \mapsto V$ given by

$f(A) = A^{T}C$ where $C = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &3 \\ 
2& 4
\end{bmatrix}$

is linear. Find $M_{\mathbf{B} \leftarrow \mathbf{B}}$"

$M_{\mathbf{B} \leftarrow \mathbf{B}} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ 
3 &4  & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$

Though I know how to solve these types of questions, I don't understand why matrices can be represened as column vectors in abstract vector spaces. I understand that in this instance, they have to be presented as column vectors, since...

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ 
3 &4  & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

... is something you can't calculate. Yet...

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ 
3 &4  & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

...is.

I've read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945166/why-a-set-of-all-2-times-2-matrices-can-be-a-vector-space#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20definition%2C%20the,is%20not%20even%20a%20vector) post, yet I'm not quite satisfied with the answer. I understand that matrices satisfy the axioms for an abstract vector space, yet the conversion from matrix...

$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$

...to column vector...

$\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
c \\
b \\
d \\
\end{pmatrix}$

...instinctively feels off.

Could someone help me out on this? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tiny error in the order of the basis elements contra the order of the entire in the column vector. That makes things look a bit weird in this answer, but hopefully it's not too big of an issue.

The matrix $$v=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$$ is just a pure, straight-forward element of $V$, a $2\times 2$ matrix. Nothing really going on here.

Now we introduce the basis $\mathbf B$. With this basis, we can write
$$
v=a\mathbf b_1 + c \mathbf b_2 + b\mathbf b_3 + d \mathbf b_4
$$
See that we have now hidden any reference to the actual form of $v$. It has been abstracted into the $\mathbf b_i$s. No longer does our notation explicitly care that $v$ is a matrix. It is an element of a vector space with a basis, and that's it.

Also note that if we remember that we are using the basis $\mathbf B$, we don't really need to write the $\mathbf b_i$. We can just write down the coefficients $a,c,b,d$ in order. And that's how we make the column vector
$$
v=\begin{pmatrix}
a \\c\\
b\\ d
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The fact that $v$ originally is a matrix is entirely forgotten in this representation. That information is baked into the basis vectors, which are now out of sight. This column is only a record of the coefficients, and nothing more. The fact that these are the same entries as in the original representation of $v$ is a coincidental by-product of $\mathbf B$ being nice, and nothing else. This is the representation that is used when we calculate things like $Mv$.

The easiest way to answer this problem in my opinion is to calculate $f(\mathbf b_i)$ for each $i$ using the basic $2\times 2$ representation, convert each result into column representation the way described above, and those would be the columns of $M$.

Comment: Going to mark this as the accepted answer. All the answers are useful, but I found this one the most insightful. Thanks Arthur :)

Comment: (Add on: fixed the error)

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback off Arthur's answer: I think your confusion is possibly arising because of how matrices and column vectors are visually alike, specially when the standard basis (the one you mentioned in your question) is the one being used, since in that case the same numbers appear in both places.

The key is realizing that in his answer "matrix" could be replaced with "vector", without specifics. The point is that, due to how vector spaces are structured, if you have an ordered basis for a given vector space, any vector belonging to that vector space is equal to some linear combination of the basis vectors. Once you have  settled on a basis, you don't need to explicity write down $\mathbf{u}=a_1\mathbf{b}_1 + a_2\mathbf{b}_2 \dots$ every single time you want to express $\mathbf{u}$ in terms of the basis vectors. What really matters are the coefficients that multiply the basis vectors. Arranging them in a column vector is a neat way of keeping track of them (in addition to being an excellent tool to deal with linear transformations).

You've probably encountered the vector space of oriented arrows in space at some point, where scalar multiplication is stretching/shortening an arrow, and adding arrows is done with the "parallelogram law". I could give you a set of three linearly independent arrows , a basis, with which you can express every other arrow as a linear combination of those basis arrows. You don't need to keep referencing those basis arrows, all that matters are those coefficients, which can be neatly arranged in a column vector. The same applies to the vector space of $2\times2$ matrices.

Comment: Really good answer. Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine 60 chairs brought in a truck be laid out in an open ground. If you choose the lay-out 5 rows of 12 columns doing them one row at a time the 34th chair  will go to the fourth position in the 7th row.

On the other direction if the chairs (after the function is over) need to be cleared and put back in truck  the then 2nd one in 8th row will become the 37th chair to be removed.

Chairs being a 2-dim or 3-dim object is of no consequence they have to be counted in a sequence and columnar arrangement arises this way naturally.  In computer programming,  for a program using 2d- or 3d- or multi-dimensional arrays (lists in Python) compiler may still be allotting from a contiguous of memory cells in RAM, which might be numbered 1 to n, making it a 1d- array (column).  From one viewpoint it is convenient (or natural) to flatten out the high-dimensional array as 1d-array (column).

Comment: Assuming we go from left to right, wouldn't the 34th chair be the 10th element of the 3rd row? Then the 37th chair to be removed, assuming we go right to left, bottom right to top left, would be the 12th element of the second row? Anyway, ty for the response!


$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 
13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24\\ 
25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36\\ 
 37& 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48\\ 
49 & 50 & 51 & 52 & 53 & 54 & 55 & 56 & 57 & 58 & 59 & 60
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Looks like I have goofed up in calculation which you have spotted. And your correction is valid. Hope my answers still conveys the idea!